# Java Reading from a text file (Strings and integers)

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have this method where i am trying to read in from a **text** file and then add whats in it to my **array** ,my method seems to be okay , but when i rum my program i am getting *null* on the screen 
please help here is my code.

```
    File text = new File("C:\\Users\\Stephen\\Desktop\\CA2\\src\\Management_System_Package\\GAMES.txt");
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

    String GameLine;
    GameLine = scnr.nextLine();

    while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

        Management_System Game = new Management_System("", "", 0, 0, 0);

        int Comma1 = GameLine.indexOf(", ");
        String Title = GameLine.substring(0, Comma1).trim();
        Game.setTitle(Title);

        System.out.print(Title);

        int Comma2 = GameLine.indexOf(", ", Comma1 + 1 );
        String Genre = GameLine.substring(Comma1 + 1, Comma2);
        Game.setGenre(Genre);

        int Comma3 = GameLine.indexOf(", ", Comma2 + 1 );
        String ID = GameLine.substring(Comma2 + 1, Comma3);
        Game.setID(Double.parseDouble(ID));

        int Comma4 = GameLine.indexOf(", ", Comma3 + 1 );
        String Rating = GameLine.substring(Comma3 + 1, Comma4);
        Game.setRating(Integer.parseInt(Rating));

        String Quantity = GameLine.substring(Comma4 + 1).trim();
        Game.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(Quantity));

        add(Game);

        GameLine = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: this is what i am trying to read from the text file

Comment: Assassins Cread, Action, 1.0, 4, 5, -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your code has a bug that you read a line out of the loop and you will always skip the last line of your file. If your file has only one line, `scnr.hasNextLine()` will be `false` and the while loop will not be run into.

And I think `split()` is a better way to get the strings and integers you want. Code like this:

```
String GameLine;

while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
    GameLine = scnr.nextLine();
    Management_System Game = new Management_System("", "", 0, 0, 0);
    String[] tags = GameLine.split(",");

    Game.setTitle(tags[0]);

    Game.setGenre(tags[1]);

    Game.setID(Double.parseDouble(tags[2]));

    Game.setRating(Integer.parseInt(tags[3]));

    Game.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(tags[4]));

    add(Game);
}
```

Comment: @StephenJpH glad to help:) I suggest you to use `split()` instead of `indexOf()`